# Red iPhone Balloon notification on a HTML input

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a notification icon, kind of like how iOS does it. I feel like I am so close, but I want the red `!` to be on the right side, and I can't figure out how... I've tried adding `text-align:right;` to the outer `<div>` with no success. Does anyone know a better way to position it?

html code

```
<form method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <div style="">
        <div class="notification-on">!</div>
        <input type="submit" name="nav" class="pure-button button-secondary" value="Notifications" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS Code

```
.notification-on{
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

What I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest setting `position: relative` to the parent `div` and then using `position: absolute` on the notification element, which allows it to be positioned relative to that parent `div`; and using `display: inline-block` to collapse the `div` down to the size of its contents:

```
div[style=""] {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.notification-on{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x4RD2/).

Answer (score 1):

For this you should try using `position: absolute` on the notification with `top: 0; right: 0;`. You will need to add `position: relative;` to the containing div which will give it context in which to be positioned. 
Your final code would look something like this, with `div.button-wrapper` being the div around the notification and the button:

```
div.button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.notification-on {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```